# Simd library compilation fails

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, static-libraries, simd-library

I'm trying to build the Simd library on Visual Studio 2017.
https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd
I opened the project from /prj/vs2017w.
I just modified the configuration type from dynamic to static lib.
And I uncommented the `#define SIMD_STATIC` from the file `SimdConfig.h`

After the compilation I get this error :

```
error MSB3073: The command "C:\Users\fullPath\Simd\prj\vs2017w\..\cmd\GetVersion.cmd
error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 9009
```

The problem is here when I click on the error :

```
<Target Name="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'$(PreBuildEventUseInBuild)'!='false'">
    <Message Text="Description: %(PreBuildEvent.Message)" Condition="'%(PreBuildEvent.Message)' != '' and '%(PreBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
    <Exec Command="%(PreBuildEvent.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)" Condition="'%(PreBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
  </Target>
```

I tried to reload the project etc but nothing works.
Also tried with VS2015 from /prj/vs2015 but same issue.

I just to want to have the Simd.lib in every configuration (x64 / x86 debug & release) for my project.

Any solution ? Thanks for help

Comment: You must look in the Output window to see the compilation error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in Visual Studio project file for Simd Library:

```
  <Command>$(ProjectDir)\..\cmd\GetVersion.cmd</Command>
```

If project directory has a space then there is an error during calling of pre build script. The solution of this error is very simple - just add quotes to the project directory:

```
  <Command>"$(ProjectDir)"\..\cmd\GetVersion.cmd</Command>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.. By looking to the output I noticed that the script stops when there is a space in the path ... So he does not have access to the .cmd file.
Thanks